# $_POST leads to empty fields in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, arrays, post

Thank you for taking the time to read this. This question may or may not have been answered before, I might have been looking in the wrong place, but I've hit a dead end wall here and I hope I could ask for some help finding a solution.

I'm using a basic form with a validation for specific fields and checkboxes before I'm sending them in a query to my database.

```
                            <?php
                            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

                                // validate the text inputs
                                $err = array();
                                if (empty($_POST['A'])) {
                                    array_push($err, "A is required.");
                                }                
                                if (empty($_POST['B'])) {
                                    array_push($err, "B is required.");
                                }
                                if (empty($_POST['C'])) {
                                    array_push($err, "C is required.");
                                } else {
                                    $pattern = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$";

                                    if (!eregi($pattern, $_POST['email'])) {
                                        array_push($err, "Incorrect email.");
                                    }
                                }        
                                if (empty($_POST['D'])) {
                                    array_push($err, "D is required.");

                                if (sizeof($err) != 0) {
                                    echo "<p style='color: red'>The following files haven't been filled yet.</p>";
                                    echo "<ul style='list-style:circle !important;color: red !important;'>";

                                    foreach ($err as &$value) {
                                        echo "<li style='background: 0;list-style: disc inside none;color: red;'>" . $value . "</li>";
                                    }

                                    echo "</ul>";
                                    echo "<br/>";
                                }

                                // validate the agree checkbox
                                if (sizeof($err) == 0 && !isset($_POST['agree'])) {
                                    array_push($err, "Please agree with the ToS.");
                                    foreach ($err as &$value) {
                                        echo "<p style='color: red'>" . $value . "</p>";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
```

Then the inside the form we got this:

```
<?php echo isset($_POST['a']) ? $_POST['a'] : ''; ?>"
```

The other lines are the same, so I'll save you from having to read a huge block. From there on I sent the code towards:

```
<?php       
// redirect if form is valid
if (sizeof($err) == 0 && isset($_POST['agree'])) { 
    // set post data in session 
    session_start();

        $_POST = $_SESSION['POSTDATA'];            
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "x", "y", "z");
                                                        // Check connection
                                                        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                                                            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                                                        }   

                                                        $sql = "INSERT INTO esselte_nl (a, b, email, c, d) VALUES
                                                            ('$_POST[a]',
                                                                '$_POST[b]',
                                                                '$_POST[email]',
                                                                '$_POST[c]',
                                                                '$_POST[d]')";

                                                        if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
                                                            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                                                        }

                                                        mysqli_close($con);
    // redirect to result.php
    exit('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=resullt"/>'); 
    return;
            session_destroy();
    }
?>
```

Worst thing is, I'm fairly certain it's some very small error somewhere and I'm overlooking it, terribly frustrating. So if anyone could potentially point out whatever I'm doing wrong here, I'd appreciate it.

With friendly regards,
user2747008 (I really should pick a name though)

PS: Sorry about that, I messed up copying pasting the information.

Comment: Can you trim down the code in your question to only essential parts?

Comment: TheSoftwareDev have the correct answer. Aditional to that I want to say: never use POST/GET Parameters directly in a SQL Statement. Use PreparedStatements and bind the values to the statemant is a much better and saver way:
http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.  http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Comment: Thing is, I added the code in the last part (with the sessions) together since I constantly got "null". Also, I'll look into PreparedStatement and SQL Injection protection. Thank you, both nbar and Andy Lester.

Comment: Alright, I seem to have fixed the problem. The issue was with the sessions that I used, as the information wasn't stored properly. By directly adding the Save Function beneath the session rather than across two pages I managed to make it work again. Now I'm going to update the safety form with the suggestions given by nbar and Andy Lester.

Thanks to everyone for their time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO esselte_nl (a, b, email, c, d) VALUES
                                                        ('$_POST[a]',
                                                            '$_POST[b]',
                                                            '$_POST[c]',
                                                            '$_POST[email]')";
```

Your insert statement has 5 field names, but only 4 values, and they aren't in the correct order.